# GET form redirecting to itself not working

Tags: html, forms, get

I have a file named draft.html with a simple GET form redirecting to itself like that:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <form action="draft.html" method="GET">
  <input type="text" id="test">
  <button type="submit">Valid</button>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I type something and click on `Valid` it redirects to `draft.html` but without the `test` parameter in the URL. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `name` attribute to your inputs (the `id` is unnecessary here unless you have related JavaScript or CSS files that use it):

```
<input type="text" name="test" id="test">
```